# iPhone, is menuCont.arrowDirection = UIMenuControllerArrowDown; not working a bug?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to add a menu controller as a quick choice of options after tapping my tab bar, however I don't get the arrow, when I use

```
menuCont.arrowDirection = UIMenuControllerArrowDown;
```

[image]

But if I use Up, Left or Right it works fine.

[image]

**Can someone else try this and advise ?**

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    UIMenuItem *menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Blue" action:@selector(blueView)];
    UIMenuItem *menuItem2 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Green" action:@selector(greenView)];
    UIMenuItem *menuItem3 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Red" action:@selector(redView)];

    UIMenuController *menuCont = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    [menuCont setTargetRect:CGRectMake(0,0,320,200) inView:self.view];
    menuCont.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:menuItem, menuItem2, menuItem3, nil];
    menuCont.arrowDirection = UIMenuControllerArrowDown;
    [menuCont setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
}
}

- (void)blueView {
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
- (void)greenView {
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
- (void)redView {
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
BOOL answer = NO;

if (action == @selector(blueView)) 
    answer = YES;

if (action == @selector(greenView)) 
    answer = YES;

if (action == @selector(redView)) 
    answer = YES;

return answer;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
return YES;
}
```

PS. I'm wondering if its old school, as it doesn't auto-complete when entering some of the menu controller code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the Documentation of the UIMenuController.

> setTargetRect:inView:
>   Sets the area in
>   a view above or below which the
>   editing menu is positioned.

which means, if you specify a rect starting at x=0 y=0, and you want a downArrow, the program tries to draw the Menu above your rect. And this is not possible because UIMenus are always in the visible area of the screen.

use `[menuCont setTargetRect:CGRectMake(0,100,320,200) inView:self.view];` and see the down-arrow

Answer (score 0):

It seems the bottom of the UIMenuController is being cut-off. Try offsetting the location:

`[menuCont setTargetRect:CGRectMake(0,-20,320,200) inView:self.view];`

Comment: Thanks but that didn't fix it :(

Comment: Did the location change at all?

Comment: Also, where is this code? Inside of a view controller or a custom tab bar class?

Comment: Its in a view. Yes it did make a difference... Ahhh  UIMenuController Class Available in iOS 3.0 and later. I'm using minimum of 3. I'm surprised it doesn't still work in the 4.1 simulator.

Comment: Not what I meant. I mean where is this code in your app located? In other words, which ".m" file?