# how to change the arrow direction of UIMenuController just before shown in an UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to change arrow direction to be up so that when it appears it does not block a top bar I set for the application. Here is the code I used to change direction:

```
UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
[menuController setArrowDirection:UIMenuControllerArrowUp];
```

and here is the result, honestly say, it is pretty stressful:[image]

It appears to be the same  issue on my iphone as well.

Can anyone look into this? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After days of researching, I finally find this way to change arrow direction of the menu controller in webview.
First, please do this in your view controller's `viewDidLoad` method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(menuControllerWillShow:) name:UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(menuControllerWillHide:) name:UIMenuControllerWillHideMenuNotification object:nil];
```

Then, add these two functions, then the arrow direction will always be pointing up, in which case the menubar will always appear below your text. (Same way, you can change `UIMenuControllerArrowUp;` to any other direction if you want your menubar to appear in other position)

```
-(void)menuControllerWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification{
    //Remove Will Show Notification to prevent
    // "menuControllerWillShow" function to be called multiple times
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification object:nil];

    //Hide the Original Menu View
    UIMenuController* menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    CGPoint origin = menuController.menuFrame.origin;
    CGSize size = menuController.menuFrame.size;
    CGRect menuFrame;
    menuFrame.origin = origin;
    menuFrame.size = size;
    [menuController setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];

    //Modify its target rect and show it again to prevent glitchy appearance
    menuController.arrowDirection = UIMenuControllerArrowUp;
    [menuController setTargetRect:menuFrame inView:self.view];
    [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];

}

-(void)menuControllerWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification{
    //re-register menuControllerWillShow
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(menuControllerWillShow:) name:UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Great answer! There were oddly some edge cases where this did not work....I ran into instances where this would correctly move the arrow, and iOS would redraw it in the "correct" orientation almost-instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html), arrowDirection sets the direction the arrow points; it has nothing to do with the location of the menu relative to its target area. It also looks like they don't give you any control over the positioning of the menu beyond setTargetRect:inView.

If you really want to put the menu below the text, you might be able to set a "fake" target area and change the arrow direction to point to the "real" area of interest.

However, there's probably a reason Apple does it this way. My guess? If you select some text with your finger, your hand is probably obscuring the part of the screen below the text... so it's not very helpful if the menu appears there. Going out of your way to break consistency with standard UI conventions isn't usually worth the effort.

[once check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145694/iphone-is-menucont-arrowdirection-uimenucontrollerarrowdown-not-working-a-bu)

Comment: Is there any way I can override UIMenuController's update function so that I just set the arrow direction to up whenever it is showing? Cause here is the snippet from the description of Update function:    By default, UIMenuController calls this method just before the editing menu is made visible and when touches occur in the menu.